Putting colored boxes around section titles in latex
I'm new to latex. I would like to place a colored box around my section titles but I don't know how to go about it. I would like to place the code for the box in the preamble within titlesec, and have the box automatically adjust to fit the size of my title, it must also not go beyond the width of a column.

You have to explain your question clearer, what you want, what you have tried, and where you got stuck. Provide an  minimal working example and the expected output will be helpful.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Does this answer solve your issue?
